# Why are option bid and ask option prices aggregated by 0.05

Tags: options

I noticed, that the option prices below strike for call and above strike for put options always end with 5 or 0. I tried placing my order with a price of 0.01 above the bid, but I haven't seen it in the table. I expected the table to contain my order with my bid a volume 1. Are the orders aggregated by 0.05?

[image: Options]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [CBOE](https://www.cboe.com/exchange_traded_stock/equity_options_spec/#:%7E:text=One%20point%20equals%20%24100.,for%20all%20other%20series%2C%20%240.10.):

> Premium Quotation Stated in decimals. One point equals \$100.
> Generally, minimum tick for options trading below \$3 is \$0.05 and for
> all other series, \$0.10. For classes participating in the Penny Pilot
> Program, the minimum tick for options trading below \$3 is \$0.01 and
> \$0.05 for options trading at \$3 or above.

Based on your screenshot, it seems it's part of the Penny Pilot Program and trades above \$3

Comment: The object of course of such rules is to allow the market-maker to earn a sufficient spread, at the detriment of the customer. Guess who it is that makes the rules.